# What permission should you take to know if you click the home button

Tags: java, android, manifest

What permission should you take to know if you click the home button. I have already used the brocast reciver but it did not come in because there is no

Comment: thats my manifest        <receiver
            android:name=".Service.InnerRecevier"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS" />
                <action android:name="com.tutorialspoint.CUSTOM_INTENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: "What permission should you take to know if you click the home button" -- there is none. If you are trying to determine when your app's UI moves to the background, use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`.

Comment: but when i push in home button or on a recent screen its no get in my brod cast reciver?what the problem?

Comment: Your `<receiver>` requires senders to hold a custom permission and use a custom action. It is unrelated to the HOME button.

Comment: So what should I write down instead?

Comment: As I wrote, if you are trying to determine when your app's UI moves to the background, use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`. Otherwise, do not worry about the HOME button.